current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist
Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (G:\Projects\Node Js\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (G:\Projects\Node Js\blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:860:11)
    at async connectDB (G:\Projects\Node Js\blog\server\config\db.js:4:22) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'cluster0-shard-00-00.af3w4.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-01.af3w4.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-02.af3w4.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-bja3zc-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

I have changed the ip od network access to anywhere and still give the same error.

Check your connection string, I can connect to your database: mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.af3w4.mongodb.net" --eval "db.hello().me" returns cluster0-shard-00-01.af3w4.mongodb.net:27017
